# Perceptual similarity problem in theoretical computer science

Tags: ds.algorithms, image-processing

A perceptual hash is a type of locality-sensitive hash, which is analogous if the features of the images are similar. Let $I$ denote the set of images and $y_1 \approx y_2 $ means images are similar (perceptually or visually). Let h denote the hash function.

$$\forall y_1,y_2 \in I, \textit{if } y_1 \approx y_2, \textit{ then } Pr[h(y_1)=h(y_2)] \ge p $$

$$\forall y_1,y_2 \in I, \textit{if } y_1 \neq y_2, \textit{ then } Pr[h(y_1)\neq(y_2)] \leq q$$

Here $p$ and $q$ denote the probabilities. The goal is to come up with a hash function $h$ which satisfies the above conditions. The hash function is referred to as a perceptual hash function. The problem has been studied in applied computer science [paper](https://gangw.cs.illinois.edu/PHashing.pdf).

**Question:** Has this problem been studied in theoretical computer science?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptual_hashing, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing